# React router consume my url request to back-end API

Tags: reactjs, rest, api, iis, asp.net-core

I'm building an SPA react-redux app at client-side, asp.net core back-end API.
Everythings run perfectly with IISExpress when debugging.
But when I deploy to IIS as a web application nested default website with the alias "mysubdomain". Everything still runs ok except export function.

(1st case): Open browser, enter download API link: http://localhost/mysubdomain/api/v1/export?filterparam. A save dialogue open. That was my expectation.

(2nd case: normal case): open my site (homepage): http://localhost/mysubdomain then click export, a new window open by the link:
http://localhost/mysubdomain/api/v1/export?filterparam.
I was expecting that savefile popup opening similar to (1st case) but **NO**. Browse return my **components/Layout** rendered.

I don't know what happening with react router/route? Or I make something wrong? I guess that react-router just consume my URL-request then render my Component, instead of call to my back-end API.

My export function inside redux store:

```
export: (filterParams) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
      const url = `api/v1/export?${filterParams}`;
      window.open(url,'_blank');
  }
```

Back-end API:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("download")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Download(DailyDischargeUrlQuery urlQuery)
{
  var stream = await _dailyDischargeRepository.ExportAsCsvStream(urlQuery.DischargeDate, urlQuery.MRN, urlQuery.GetCompanies(), urlQuery.GetOrders());

  return File(stream, "text/csv", "dailydischarge.csv");
}
```

index.js

```
const baseUrl = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].getAttribute('href');
const history = createBrowserHistory({ basename: baseUrl });
const initialState = window.initialReduxState;
const store = configureStore(history, initialState);    
const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <App />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  rootElement);

registerServiceWorker();
```

App.js

```
import 'core-js';
import React from 'react';
import {Route, Router} from 'react-router';
import Layout from './components/Layout';
import Home from './components/Home';

export default () => (
    <Layout>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
    </Layout>
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been resolved!
That because of service worker built-in create-react-app.

```
// In production, we register a service worker to serve assets from local cache.

// This lets the app load faster on subsequent visits in production, and gives
// it offline capabilities. However, it also means that developers (and users)
// will only see deployed updates on the "N+1" visit to a page, since previously
// cached resources are updated in the background.
```